# WOPI host disable auto-saving

Tags: c#, ms-wopi

I'm implementing WOPI host app. After I edit document, Word Online automatically saves it. Can I disable auto-saving? And if yes, how can I do that? Can I add simply "Save" button and use it instead auto-saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't refer to FAQs [WOPI Disable Autosave FAQs](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/disable_autosave.html)